# How to match tab length to a number of spaces in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit

I'm having trouble making tabs in a QTextEdit be the same size as some number of spaces, say 4.

I'm using Qt 4.8.1 on a mac and I've tried several different monospace fonts. In each case I try using fontMetrics.width() and fontMetrics.boundingRect().width(). Passing in the ' ' and multiplying by 4 and passing in "    " return me consistant sizes, but when I set the tab stop width it's slightly off. What's worse, the error accumulates. If I type 6 tabs and, below, 6 * 4 spaces, the curser ends up in a dramatically different place.

Even tweaking the number by hand I have been unable to find an integer number of pixels that exactly matches and keeps tabs and equivalent spaces consistant.

Has anyone else encountered this issue? Have you found a solution other than to replace tabs with spaces?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use this?

```
QFontMetrics::tightBoundingRect("    ")
```

I found the suggestion here, but unfortunately it doesn't mention whether it was successful: http://lists.qt.nokia.com/pipermail/qt-interest/2009-June/007924.html

Please let me know if it works for you :)

Comment: Thanks, but alas, I have tried that with no success >.<

But regardless, the thing I'm most concerned with is that I cannot find an integer value that keeps tabs and spaces equivalent. In other words, I cannot find an integer that those functions could return that would work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with you,and I call `setTabStopWidth(4 * fontMetrics().width(' '));`in QPlainTextEdit constructor.But when I call it after its constructor, it can work!I don't know the magic behind it...